# my function-definition seems not get included in void loop

Tags: c, function, arduino, arduino-ide, arduino-c++

I was practicing and trying my Analog to Digital Converter and trying this simple test. And here is my code :

```
#include <Adafruit_MCP3008.h>

Adafruit_MCP3008 adc;

  float voltage(int raw){
  return raw / 1023 * 4.9;
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial);
  Serial.println("MCP3008 simple test.");

  adc.begin();
  
}

void loop() {
  int raw = adc.readADC(0);

  Serial.print(raw);
  Serial.print("\t");
  Serial.println(voltage(raw));

  delay(1000);
}
```

and when I opened my serial monitor it only showing the changes of "raw", but my "voltage" function seems not get included, here is what I got, as you can see it only shows the result for raw (on left), but not showing the voltage (on right) [serial monitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PcqK7.png)

I'm trying to make sure I got the "voltage" function affected also inside the void loop. can anybody explain me the rule of program in this case ?

Comment: `raw / 1023` this is done using integer division

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the behavior of integer division?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3602827/what-is-the-behavior-of-integer-division)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have a conversion problem. You are passing a int and divide it by 1023. This would give you 0, then multiplied by 4.9 would give you 0.0

You should cast your int raw into a float.

Comment: Or do a floating point division `raw / 1023.0 * 4.9`

Comment: @OlafDietsche, note that with `raw / 1023.0 * 4.9` you are suggesting a `double` divide and this answer does a `float` divide.

Answer (score 3):

**Integer division**

`raw / 1023` results in 0, 1, ....  Not a fraction.

**Use `float` math instead of `double`**

For a `float` task, use `float` constants.  This avoids a lot of unneeded widening and narrowing of floating point code.

```
float voltage(int raw){
  // double divide, double *, convert to float
  // return raw / 1023.0 * 4.9;

  // float divide, float *
  return raw / 1023.0f * 4.9f;
}
```

**Help the compiler**

Strict code complilation cannot combine the `/` and `*`, incurring 2 operations including a heavy `/`.  FP math is not associative.  Yet we can in source code.

Also avoid naked magic numbers.

```
#define ADC_V_MAX 4.9f
#define ADC_N_MAX 1023 
float voltage(int raw){
  return raw * (ADC_V_MAX / ADC_N_MAX);
}
```

**Sure about range?**

I'd expect:

```
#define ADC_V_MAX 5.0f
#define ADC_N_MAX 1024
```

A 10-bit A/D converter typically maps 1024 to the top voltage 5.0, even though only 0-1023 is produced.

Answer (score 1):

turn out it was not the function definition, it was mathematical order, silly me :sweat_smile:

this fixed my issue :

```
float voltage(int raw)
{
return (raw * 4.9) / 1023 ;
}
```

Comment: Note that `(raw * 4.9) / 1023` performs a `double *, double /, convert to float` when only a `float *` is needed.